# Regression in a one-to-many dataset

Tags: r, regression, logistic

I'm rather new to R and am working with an unfamiliar dataset format containing patient discharge records. The records are distributed in a typical SQL format with matching key pairs. I'm attempting to look for predictors of length of stay as a result of surgery and have been joining the dataset together in R. When using a left_join for example on the discharge record table to diagnosis table, patients often have multiple diagnosis codes to a single discharge so such a procedure duplicates that discharge row for the number of codes. 
For example:

```
Discharge Table:

  Discharge_ID    Length of Stay
  1               2
  2               13
  3               5

Diagnosis Table:

  Diagnosis_ID    Discharge_ID   Code
  1               1              001
  2               1              052
  3               3              356

left_join(Discharge Table, Diagnosis Table):

  Discharge_ID    Length of Stay   Code
  1               2                001
  1               2                052
  2               13               NA
  3               5                356
```

Given that the duplication increases the data points for length of stay of records with codes, does this impact regression analysis and if so, is there a way to correct for it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you seem to be saying is that each patient can have more than one diagnosis and that you want to predict length of stay. We can ignore the stuff about SQL and joins - it doesn't seem relevant here and is off topic in any case. 

I am sure questions like this have been asked here before, but I could not find them. Maybe someone else can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend re-shaping the data so that for each patient you have a single "length of stay" - this is your dependent variable, and you should have one per row.

Given that you can have multiple diagnosis codes per "length of stay", or even no diagnosis code at all, the best approach might be to dummy code your "diagnosis code" into many binary columns. e.g.

```
Discharge_ID    Length_of_stay    Diagnosis_001    Diagnosis_052   Diagnosis_356
           1                 2                1                1               0
           2                13                0                0               0
           3                 5                0                0               1
```

Then try predicting "length_of_stay" using the rest of the table, minus "discharge_id".

This kind of dummy coding and data manipulation is easy to do in R - have a look at dplyr package for data manipulation. The caret package has some useful dummy coding functions.

Comment: Thanks so much, I think using the spread function here should be able to distribute it like that. I'll give it a go

Comment: Yes, I think the spread function should work as you want. If this has helped with your question, can you mark it as answered.